# How to Transcode m4v to wmv/asf

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, media

How can I transcode a m4v http stream to a wmv/asf http stream

I've tried ffmpeg but I can't seem to get the right switchs and ideas?

Comment: It will be windows im am going to launch it from c# if that helps

Comment: Well if it was unix it would help because you could use gstreamer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLC should be up to the task. Download VLC and play with it. Use the network stream functionality, pass it through some filters, and then send it back out. After you figure out the mrl, just use PInvoke and the vlc bindings to do it programmatically.